# Using GetDataTable() hoses my SPFieldLookValueCollection!

Tags: object-model, datatable

I am trying to use GetDataTable on an SPListItemCollection.  I have run into a situation where my SPFieldLookupValueCollections in this list are being converted to a string when they are stored in the DataTable.

Is it possible for me to store these values as SPFieldLookupValueCollections objects instead of strings?

Comment: Yeah I [asked a similar question a while ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488460/splistitemcollection-getdatatable-doesnt-return-all-columns). TL;DR Write your own GetDataTable method (which is what you found out also it seems).

Answer (score 4):

Apparently this is a known issue.  I ended up using the following method that I found [here](http://www.fftf.org/news/Mar07feed/SPListItemCollectionGetDataTable_Bug.rss.html), to resolve the issue:

```
    DataTable CreateDataTableFromListItemCollection(SPListItemCollection itemCollection)
    {
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        if (itemCollection.Count > 0)
            tbl.TableName = itemCollection[0].ParentList.Title;

        if (itemCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            // Take the first item and generate all columns
            //tbl.TableName = itemCollection[0].Title;
            foreach (SPField curField in itemCollection.Fields)
            {
                DataColumn col = new DataColumn(curField.InternalName);
                tbl.Columns.Add(col);
            }
            foreach (SPListItem item in itemCollection)
            {
                DataRow row = tbl.NewRow();
                foreach (SPField field in itemCollection.Fields)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        row[field.InternalName] = item[field.InternalName];
                    }
                    catch { continue; } // Gah...
                }
                tbl.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
        return tbl;
    }
```

Hope this helps someone!